# How to compare two time and choice time small in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question. I have two time : time01: 11:00 and time02: 11.02. Because it input by user, i don't know when time01 small or time02 small. 
Example : I have booking and when user input it look like :

```
Insert into table01("time01,"time02") values ("11:01",11:02)
```

I want using postgres sql create funtion("or sql...) get data from user and compare it. I want choice time small and after that i get time small from time01 and time02 and do something. How to i can work it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is probably just to create a view or query to get the values in the order you want:

```
select least(time1, time2) as time_first,
       greatest(time1, time2) as time_second
from table01;
```

If you want users to only be able to input the times in the correct order, then use a check constraint:

```
alter table table01 add constraint chk_table01_time1_time2
    check (time1 < time2);
```

This will reject out-of-order inputs.

Finally, if you want the two times in the right order regardless of the order they are supplied to the table, then use a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question but I believe you may want to store the times in order even if the user didn't enter it correctly? Then you can use `least()` and `greatest()`. The first one returns the smallest of its arguments, the second one the largest. So you could do:

```
INSERT INTO table01
            (time01,
             time02)
            VALUES (least('11:01',
                          '11:02'),
                    greatest('11:01',
                             '11:02'));
```

---

Edit:

If you only want to save the smaller one of the times just use `least()` and save it where ever you want. Assuming the target is a column `milestone` in a table `milestones`:

```
INSERT INTO milestones
            (milestone)
            VALUES (least('11:01',
                          '11:02'));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I mean, I need to compare the two time from from arguments(time01,time02). If time01> time 02. I will save the time 02 ...

Comment: @TrungSquall: Then only use `least()`. See the edit.